# installing theme manually

Tags: themes

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.  I found a great theme I would really like and downloaded it.  It is in a zip file and I cannot figure out how to install it.
I tried the `/usr/shared/themes` but it tells me I do not have permission to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to extract it first.

To install globally (i.e. to install it such that it is available for all users, you need to place it in `/usr/share/themes`.

For this you need root privileges. A simple way to achieve this would be to open `nautilus` as root and then copy paste the extracted theme folder.

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window.
In the terminal window that opens do:

```
sudo nautilus
```

A window will show up. Copy your extracted theme folder and paste it into `/usr/share/themes`. (Close the window when you're done.)

If you do not have root privileges, copy your extracted theme folder to `~/.themes/` where `~` stands for your home and `.` makes the folder hidden – simply create one if there isn't any.

After all, you need apps such as [Unity Tweak Tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unity-tweak-tool) to select the theme.